# Transform-scale parent size, but keep child the same size

Tags: css, sass

Currently I have a DIV with SPAN inside it, I want to scale on hover only DIV without scaling SPAN, is it possible?
HTML sctructure:

```
<div class="bg-img" style="background: url(<?php the_field('home_4_bg_img'); ?>) bottom / cover no-repeat">
   <span class="bg-caption"><?php the_field('home_4_bg_caption'); ?></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't think there's such a property in css which can match your requirement, you could search for other ways to solve it.
maybe you could absolutely position that php img(home_4_bg_img), then only scale it when user hovers on it